# How to get nested complexType parameters for an operation from a SOAP wsdl in c#

Tags: c#, parsing, soap, wsdl, complextype

Having an WSDL and given one operation offered by it I want to parse it and fetch the input parameters for that operation, this example works for me only when there are no nested complex types:

[How to parse an xsd file which has nested elements(complexType and simpleType elements and attributes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969063/how-to-parse-an-xsd-file-which-has-nested-elementscomplextype-and-simpletype-el)

For this it works:

http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl

And that means it returns for all 4 operations the correct parameters (Add has AddSoapIn with intA and intB...)

but for this doesn't:

http://www.learnwebservices.com/services/hello?WSDL

It gets only to the HelloRequest for SayHello and does not fetch the element Name from HelloRequest.

This should work for any and not specific SOAP WSDLs, what I mean is a generic parsing.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
public TheClient(string url) {
    wsdlUrl = url;
    ReadServiceDescription();
    ServiceName = theService.Name;
}
```

...

```
void ReadServiceDescription()
    {
        try
        {               
            XmlTextReader reader=new XmlTextReader (wsdlUrl);   
            ServiceDescription service=
                ServiceDescription.Read(reader);
            theService = service;
            _services.Add(service);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                                                       
            throw e;
        }
    }

private static List<Tuple<string, string>> getParams(string methodName, XmlSchema schemaXML)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, string>> parameters = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        ServiceDescription serviceDescription = theService;
        XmlSchema xmlSchema;
        WebClient client = new WebClient(); ;
        //Drill down into the WSDL's complex types to list out the individual schema elements
        //and their data types
        Types types = serviceDescription.Types;
        if (schemaXML != null)
        {
            xmlSchema = schemaXML;
        } else
        {
            xmlSchema = types.Schemas[0];
        }
    foreach (object item in xmlSchema.Items)
    {
        XmlSchemaElement schemaElement = item as XmlSchemaElement;
        XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = item as XmlSchemaComplexType;

        if (schemaElement != null && methodName == schemaElement.Name)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Schema Element: {0}", schemaElement.Name);

            XmlSchemaType schemaType = schemaElement.SchemaType;
            XmlSchemaComplexType schemaComplexType = schemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;

            if (schemaComplexType != null)
            {
                XmlSchemaParticle particle = schemaComplexType.Particle;
                XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;
                if (sequence != null)
                {
                    foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
                    {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("    Element/Type: {0}:{1}", childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name);
                        parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (complexType != null && complexType.Name == methodName)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Complex Type: {0}", complexType.Name);
            List<Tuple<string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(complexType.Particle);
            if(moreparams != null && moreparams.Count !=0)
            {
                parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
            }
        }
        //Console.Out.WriteLine();
    }
    // Loop through all detected imports in the main schema
    List<Tuple<string, string>> importparameters = ImportIncludedSchemasRecursively(wsdlUrl, methodName, xmlSchema);
    if (importparameters != null && importparameters.Count != 0)
    {
        parameters.AddRange(importparameters);
    }
    return parameters;
}

private static List<Tuple<string, string>> ImportIncludedSchemasRecursively(string mainWsdlUrl, string methodName, XmlSchema currentWsdlSchema)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string>> parameters = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    foreach (XmlSchemaObject externalSchema in currentWsdlSchema.Includes)
    {
        // Read each external schema into a schema object
        if (externalSchema is XmlSchemaImport)
        {
            Uri baseUri = new Uri(mainWsdlUrl);
            Uri schemaUri = new Uri(baseUri, ((XmlSchemaExternal)externalSchema).SchemaLocation);

            WebClient http = new WebClient();
            Stream schemaStream = http.OpenRead(schemaUri);

            System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, null);
            List<Tuple<string, string>> complexparams = getParams(methodName, schema);
            if (complexparams != null && complexparams.Count != 0)
            {
                parameters.AddRange(complexparams);
            }

            List<Tuple<string, string>> morecomplexparams = ImportIncludedSchemasRecursively(mainWsdlUrl.ToString(), methodName, schema);
            if (morecomplexparams != null && morecomplexparams.Count != 0)
            {
                parameters.AddRange(morecomplexparams);
            }

        }
    }

    return parameters.Distinct().ToList();
}

private static List<Tuple<string, string>> OutputElements(XmlSchemaParticle particle)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string>> parameters = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;
    XmlSchemaChoice choice = particle as XmlSchemaChoice;
    XmlSchemaAll all = particle as XmlSchemaAll;

    if (sequence != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("111 child: {0}", childElement.Name);
            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name));
            }
            else {
                List<Tuple<string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }
        }

        return parameters;
    }
    else if (choice != null)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("  Choice");
        for (int i = 0; i < choice.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("222 child: {0}", childElement.Name);
            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name));
            }
            else
            {                       
                List<Tuple<string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }

        }
        return parameters;
    }
    else if (all != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < all.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("333 child: {0}", childElement.Name);
            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                List<Tuple<string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

when I call getParams for SayHello it displays on command line:
[image]

first debug from line 49 (in code of previous comment ;)),
second from line 70
and last one from line 138 of OutputElements function.

I also tried a to get the complexType, in this case HelloRequest, when there at line 139 is not null (childElement) and added as param,

and transform it to complex type:

```
XmlSchemaComplexType complexTypeChild = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaComplexType;
```

similar as the SayHello, parent of HelloRequest is processed, and call for it again same function OutputElements with complexTypeChild, recursive

so then if has other child will work

but complexTypeChild is null.

I have chanced the OutputElements like this:

```
private static List<Tuple<string, string, string>> OutputElements(XmlSchemaParticle particle, string parentName)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> parameters = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

    XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;
    XmlSchemaChoice choice = particle as XmlSchemaChoice;
    XmlSchemaAll all = particle as XmlSchemaAll;

    if (sequence != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, parentName));
                // if it has children
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = getParams(childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, null);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }
            else {
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle, parentName);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }
        }

        return parameters;
    }
    else if (choice != null)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("  Choice");
        for (int i = 0; i < choice.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, parentName));
            }
            else
            {                        
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle, parentName);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }

        }
        return parameters;
    }
    else if (all != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < all.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, parentName));
            }
            else
            {
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle, parentName);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

see the 5 lines after

```
// if it has children
```

so if found then check if has children, also I added the parent parameter/element to the param so I can use it when creating the envelope to call that operation with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now it works, the problem was that the solution I used the code from, initially: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969063/how-to-parse-an-xsd-file-which-has-nested-elementscomplextype-and-simpletype-el)

was actually made custom for a type of wsdl, with one deep level of complexTypes, and I needed to work for ANY wsdl, I have now tried for a few I have and it works but it might be that I will find an example with some complex stuff that will not work for, in that case I will come back here and post the fixed code.

Anyway the solution is this, at least for now as I say it seems to work for document and rpc and soap 1.1 and soap 1.2 wsdls:

```
private static List<Tuple<string, string, string>> getParams(string methodName, XmlSchema schemaXML)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> parameters = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
    ServiceDescription serviceDescription = theService;
    XmlSchema xmlSchema;
    WebClient client = new WebClient(); ;
    //Drill down into the WSDL's complex types to list out the individual schema elements 
    //and their data types
    Types types = serviceDescription.Types;
    if (schemaXML != null)
    {
        xmlSchema = schemaXML;
    } else
    {
        xmlSchema = types.Schemas[0];
    }

    foreach (object item in xmlSchema.Items)
    {
        XmlSchemaElement schemaElement = item as XmlSchemaElement;
        XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = item as XmlSchemaComplexType;

        if (schemaElement != null && methodName == schemaElement.Name)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Schema Element: {0}", schemaElement.Name);

            XmlSchemaType schemaType = schemaElement.SchemaType;
            XmlSchemaComplexType schemaComplexType = schemaType as XmlSchemaComplexType;

            if (schemaComplexType != null)
            {
                XmlSchemaParticle particle = schemaComplexType.Particle;
                XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;
                if (sequence != null)
                {
                    foreach (XmlSchemaElement childElement in sequence.Items)
                    {
                        parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, schemaElement.Name));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (complexType != null && complexType.Name == methodName)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Complex Type: {0}", complexType.Name);
            List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(complexType.Particle, complexType.Name);
            if(moreparams != null && moreparams.Count !=0)
            {
                parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
            }
        }
    }
    // Loop through all detected imports in the main schema
    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> importparameters = ImportIncludedSchemasRecursively(wsdlUrl, methodName, xmlSchema);
    if (importparameters != null && importparameters.Count != 0)
    {
        parameters.AddRange(importparameters);
    }
    return parameters;
}

private static List<Tuple<string, string, string>> ImportIncludedSchemasRecursively(string mainWsdlUrl, string methodName, XmlSchema currentWsdlSchema)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> parameters = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

    foreach (XmlSchemaObject externalSchema in currentWsdlSchema.Includes)
    {
        // Read each external schema into a schema object
        if (externalSchema is XmlSchemaImport)
        {
            Uri baseUri = new Uri(mainWsdlUrl);
            Uri schemaUri = new Uri(baseUri, ((XmlSchemaExternal)externalSchema).SchemaLocation);

            WebClient http = new WebClient();
            Stream schemaStream = http.OpenRead(schemaUri);

            System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, null);
            List<Tuple<string, string, string>> complexparams = getParams(methodName, schema);
            if (complexparams != null && complexparams.Count != 0)
            {
                parameters.AddRange(complexparams);
            }

            List<Tuple<string, string, string>> morecomplexparams = ImportIncludedSchemasRecursively(mainWsdlUrl.ToString(), methodName, schema);
            if (morecomplexparams != null && morecomplexparams.Count != 0)
            {
                parameters.AddRange(morecomplexparams);
            }

        }
    }

    return parameters.Distinct().ToList();
}

private static List<Tuple<string, string, string>> OutputElements(XmlSchemaParticle particle, string parentName)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> parameters = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

    XmlSchemaSequence sequence = particle as XmlSchemaSequence;
    XmlSchemaChoice choice = particle as XmlSchemaChoice;
    XmlSchemaAll all = particle as XmlSchemaAll;

    if (sequence != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, parentName));
                // if it has children
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = getParams(childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, null);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }
            else {
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(sequence.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle, parentName);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }
        }

        return parameters;
    }
    else if (choice != null)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("  Choice");
        for (int i = 0; i < choice.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, parentName));
            }
            else
            {                        
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(choice.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle, parentName);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }

        }
        return parameters;
    }
    else if (all != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < all.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlSchemaElement childElement = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaElement;
            XmlSchemaSequence innerSequence = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaSequence;
            XmlSchemaChoice innerChoice = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaChoice;
            XmlSchemaAll innerAll = all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaAll;

            if (childElement != null)
            {
                parameters.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(childElement.Name, childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, parentName));
            }
            else
            {
                List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = OutputElements(all.Items[i] as XmlSchemaParticle, parentName);
                if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
                {
                    parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
                }
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

This, given ANY parsed wsdl, see the initial/original post's code for this, will give for a operation the parameters to call it with together with the parent for each.

Answer (score 0):

I took the WSDL and removed the schema section.   Then ran the xsd.exe on the section and go the following c# classes

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.33440.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://learnwebservices.com/services/hello")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://learnwebservices.com/services/hello", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class SayHello {
    
    private helloRequest helloRequestField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public helloRequest HelloRequest {
        get {
            return this.helloRequestField;
        }
        set {
            this.helloRequestField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://learnwebservices.com/services/hello")]
public partial class helloRequest {
    
    private string nameField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://learnwebservices.com/services/hello")]
public partial class helloResponse {
    
    private string messageField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Message {
        get {
            return this.messageField;
        }
        set {
            this.messageField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://learnwebservices.com/services/hello")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://learnwebservices.com/services/hello", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class SayHelloResponse {
    
    private helloResponse helloResponseField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public helloResponse HelloResponse {
        get {
            return this.helloResponseField;
        }
        set {
            this.helloResponseField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, I did the same for specific services, by using SvcUtil.exe though. But I want my code, that resides into a .Net component, to use ANY WSDL and generate the stub call to the SOAP service methods. I made it work for soap 1.1. and 1.2 and for document and rpc style and for most of the situations, even imported XSDs, except this part that for operations with nested complexTypes it does not work recursively until the last element.

Comment: The schema has two roots SayHello and helloResponse.  How does you  code know the roots?  When you get a response the Controller has to be set to the Root Tag.  For the code to work dynamically you would have to set the controller to match the response you are expecting.   You can search web for ways of setting the controller dynamically.

Comment: I am parsing the WSDL, will add the code I use in the post.

Comment: Can you debug code and indicate what is not working?

Comment: I did and found out that add another recursive level, in OutputElements to call getParams once you found somethin, in case has children. Also I add the parent name for each param to use it when I create the envelope, for calling the service operation. Now it works, I will change the original code also but the part(s) is like this, after founding and adding a param in OutputElements:    List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moreparams = getParams(childElement.SchemaTypeName.Name, null);
     if (moreparams != null && moreparams.Count != 0)
     {
      parameters.AddRange(moreparams);
     }

Comment: The WSDL does not match the response.  The WSDL does not have an array while you XML Response does.  So you solution is just a work around for a bad WSDL.